# Unit-Testing with Karma not calling functions

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to perform unit testing with Karma. I have done everything according to the documentation. When I write this part of the test that follows it never calls the last two functions.

```
it('should create the mock object', function (done) {

    service.createObj(mockObj)
        .then(test)
        .catch(failTest)
        .finally(done);
});
var test = function() {
    expect(2).toEqual(1);
};

var failTest = function(error) {
    expect(2).toEqual(1);
};
```

Comment: any error in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to inject into your beforeEach function rootScope. For example like this:

```
var rootScope;

beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_) {
    rootScope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    //other injections
}));
```

and next invoke $digest() after your service method:

```
it('should create the mock object', function (done) {
    service.createObj(mockObj)
        .then(test)
        .catch(failTest)
        .finally(done);

    rootScope.$digest();
});
```

Comment: why he should call rootScope.$digest(); !? there is no need for this (and no need to injec $rootScope), to test a data service, just use $httpBackend to mock your server return, there is a a lot of answers that describe how to test a service object.

Comment: It worked using the proposed solution. I was trying by using just $httpBackend but it wouldn't work.

Comment: I had the same problem few months ago and this solution resolved my problem. I don't know why, but in unit tests Angular don't fire promiess automatically and needs help by invoking rootScope.$digest().

Comment: It only worked once though... and then I am getting an :"Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress"
Tried adding 
if (rootScope.$$phase)
        rootScope.$digest();
but still the same error occurs

Answer (score 0):

- Install angular-mocks module.
- Inject module with module in beforeEach.
- Inject your service with inject function in beforeEach.
- Use $httpBackend to simulate your server.
- Do, not forget, to make it, sync. with $http.flush().